# Make given number of points at evenly spaced on line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a shapefile lines representing historical flight paths of aerial photography. I have the number of photos taken for each path and the number of the first and last photo, plus the ID of the flight path.
I can do this manually with the "construct points" tool in ArcGIS, Spatial Join and some grunt work but I want to make this an automated process.
Task includes:

1. Make points along lines with equal intervals, including both ends, with information on the # of points from the lines shapefile.
2. Get LineID from the lines shp to the pnts shp (Guessing Spatial Join is the only way to go).
3. Allocate photo-numbers to points from only knowing first and last photo-number for each line, and the direction of the line.

If nothing else, getting the points on the lines would be a good start.

Comment: Did you have a look at the QChainage plugin in QGIS?

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS there is a tool that can create points along a line.

You can find it in the Processing Toolbox under GRASS commands.

Activate the Processing toolbox, if need be:

[image]

Open the Processing toolbox:

[image]

Activate the advanced interface, if need be:

[image]

And then navigate to the *GRASS commands*, and you will find *v.to.points*:

[image]